# User Settings Button missing after upgrade from TYPO3 10 LTS to 11 LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

There is no way for a backend user to edit the user settings because the button is missing. I open this issue because I could not find anything related to this problem using Google. This must be a known issue, I simply upgraded via composer, ran through all migrations and now the button is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems some package removed a dependency and so i had to put the package `typo3/cms-setup` to the local composer.json.

You can fix this by installing the package.

```bash
composer require typo3/cms-setup:^11.5
```

I could find the reason for my issue by inspecting the list of needed packages from this meta-package:

https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-base-distribution

Comment: Another possibility to find the necessary (and available) composer packages is the [composer helper](https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/helper). There just select the desired TYPO3 version and TYPO3/MINIMAL.